# in activeadmin form input not working in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

in active_admin:
some code not work like this:

```
form do |f|
 f.inputs "title" do
   %w(AreaGroupId DescriptionFlags Dispel Mechanic modalNextSpell).each do |ele|
     f.input ele
   end
  end
end
```

when i write other format like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "title" do
     f.input AreaGroupId
     f.input DescriptionFlags
     f.input Dispel
     f.input Mechanic
     f.input modalNextSpell
  end
end
```

so the can run

why ? something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because how Formtastic works, the block given to `f.inputs` has to return the last input. If you want a quick fix, try the following:

```
form do |f|
 f.inputs "title" do
   %w(AreaGroupId DescriptionFlags Dispel Mechanic modalNextSpell).map do |ele|
     f.input ele
   end.last
  end
end
```